# Для чего нужен модификатор transient?

Tags: java

Каково назначение модификатора `transient` в Java?

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910374/

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Сериализация - это преобразование экземпляра класса в форму, пригодную для его сохранения (например в файл, в БД или для передачи по сети). Сериализованные объекты можно затем восстановить (десериализовать).

Свойства класса, помеченные модификатором `transient`, не сериализуются.

Обычно в таких полях хранится промежуточное состояние объекта, которое, к примеру, проще вычислить, чем сериализовать, а затем десериализовать. Другой пример такого поля — ссылка на экземпляр объекта, который не требует сериализации или не может быть сериализован.